# How can we rescale the time in the differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$Ax'(t)+ Bx(t)=Du(t)$$
where $t\in[0,T_f]$.

I want to rescale the time $t\in[0,T_f]$ to $[0,1]$.

How can we rescale it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. What have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Do you know any function which remaps the end points as you want them to become?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm willing to explain this in full detail since just writing $x(\tau)$ and $u(\tau)$ feels wrong (abuse of notation) and non-intuitive to me.

Let $\tau := t/T_f$, then $t \in [0, T_f]$ maps to $\tau \in [0,1]$. Note that $t=T_f \ \tau$ and $\dfrac{{\rm d}t}{{\rm d}\tau} =T_f$.

Let $y(\tau) := x(t)=x(T_f \ \tau)$ and $v(\tau) := u(t) =u(T_f \ \tau)$.
Then (chain rule)
$$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}\tau} =\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} \frac{{\rm d}t}{{\rm d}\tau} =T_f \ \dot x(t), \qquad\text{so that }\dot x(t) =\frac{1}{T_f} \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}\tau}.$$
Then rewrite the ODE in terms of $\tau$ and $y$: $$\frac{A}{T_f} \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}\tau} +B \ y(\tau) = D \ v(\tau).$$

Comment: Good answer. These things are rarely explained in full detail, but seeing the full detail at least once is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\hbox{With} \ \ \ \ \ t = \lambda \tau\\
\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = \frac{d}{d\tau}x(\tau)\frac{d\tau}{dt} = \frac{1}{\lambda}\dot x(\tau)
$$

Comment: Thanks. But I found as follows. $$
\hbox{With} \ \ \ \ \ t = \lambda \tau\\
\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = \frac{d}{dt}x(\lambda \tau)=\frac{d}{d\tau}x(\lambda\tau)\frac{d\tau}{dt} = \frac{1}{\lambda}\dot x(\lambda\tau)
$$. Is it same thing with yours? How?

Comment: Suppose you have to solve $A \dot x(t) + B x(t) = c$ It gives $x(t) = \frac{c}{B}+e^{-\frac{B}{A}t}$  Now solving $\frac{A}{\lambda}\dot x(\tau) + B x(\tau) = c$ we obtain $x(\tau) = \frac{c}{B}+e^{-\frac{B}{A}\lambda \tau}$ which is correct.